# Use a regular expression for CMake find_path hints

Tags: c++, regex, cmake, arduino

Using CMake's `find_path`, I'm actualy searching some file in the `/usr/share/arduino` folder, with a very simple `find_path`:

```
find_path(ARDUINO_SDK_PATH
      NAMES lib/version.txt hardware libraries
      PATH_SUFFIXES share/arduino
      DOC "Arduino Development Kit path.")
```

The problem is that it seems on some distributions (for example, [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux)), the Arduino SDK is packaged, and installed in `/usr/share/arduino-version`. In fact, I try to search in all the folders beginning with "arduino", in `/usr/share`. I tried to add a `*` at the end of the `PATH_SUFFIXES`, but that's not working.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [file(GLOB ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afile) command.